# getting "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have gone through several questions related to this looking for an answer but have not found one. So here is the code that produced the error:

```
function centerGalImages() {
    var len = $('.image').filter(':visible').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ {
        var contWidth = $('.img-container')[i].width();
        var imgWidth = $('.image')[i].width();
        var leftOffset = (contWidth/2) - (imgWidth/2);
        img.css({left: leftOffset});
    }
}
```

I am getting the error with calling `width()`.
I am fairly new to JS/JQuery but to me this looks like it should work. The `css` files are loaded into the `html` file before the `jquery` file and here is the css related to `.image` and `.img-container`:

```
.image {
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

.img-container {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 24.5%;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

any Ideas on why the call to `width()` is not working is greatly appreciated

EDIT: as requested here is the relevent HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="img-container"><img class="image clickable" src=""/></div>
    <div class="img-container"><img class="image clickable" src=""/></div>
    ...container/image elements are copied 16 times...
</div>
```

the `src` values are set at the beginning of the jquery file. so by time `centerGalImages()` is called the `src` values have been set

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('.img-container')[i].width()')`

Comment: Can you also add your HTML, you code can be much simpler, but need to see HTML structure.

Comment: Notice, that `$('.img-container')` returns a [jQuery object](http://jsfiddle.net/xydfbe2c/) which is not an array

Comment: @Teemu, there is more than one div with `.img-container` so it does in fact return an array.

Comment: It's not, you didn't take a look at the linked fiddle ...

Comment: @Teemu My apologies, though I have checked to see what `$('.img-container')[i]` returns and it does return a div object as far as I can tell

Comment: Yes, that really returns you a _native_ DOM element (as a result of a jQuery method), that's why it has not jQuery methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code

```
$('.img-container')[i].width();
```

you are trying to call `width` method of the `HTMLImageElement`. Which doesn't exist. Hence the error. `width` is the method of jQuery instance, so it should be

```
$('.img-container').eq(i).width();
```

**UPD.** According to HTML structure, this might look better:

```
$('.image').filter(':visible').css('left', function() {
    var contWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var imgWidth = $(this).width();
    return (contWidth/2) - (imgWidth/2);
});
```

Comment: `.img-container` references more than 1 `div` so shouldn't `$('.img-container')` return an array of `div`s

Comment: Yes, I noticed. In this case you should use `$.fn.eq` method to get corresponding container by index. But better provide HTML so I can give you much better solution.

Comment: will this adjust the position for each image seperately or will all images have the same position within its parent element?

Comment: It will calculate `left` individually for each image base on its width and width of the parent.